# Remove background

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, scikit-image

I am doing OCR to extract information from the ID card. However, accuracy is quite low.

My assumption is that removing the background will make OCR more accurate.

I use the ID scanner machine ([link](http://www.sinosecu.com.cn/en/show/view/7.html?gclid=CjwKCAjw5vz2BRAtEiwAbcVIL1uy3o1rCeepy6_iTHfXcPErTCbbMfr75Bz1VdNbZU-FVHzuQx3zbxoCCCcQAvD_BwE)) to obtain the grey image below. It seems that the machine uses IR instead of image processing.

**Does anyone knows how to get the same result by using Opencv or tools (photoshop, gimp, etc)?**

Thanks in advance.

[image: original]
[image: processed]

Answer (score 2):

Here are two more methods: adaptive thresholding and division normalization.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("green_card.jpg")

# convert img to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# do adaptive threshold on gray image
thresh1 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 51, 25)

# write results to disk
cv2.imwrite("green_card_thresh1.jpg", thresh1)


# apply morphology
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT , (11,11))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# divide gray by morphology image
division = cv2.divide(gray, morph, scale=255)

# threshold
thresh2 = cv2.threshold(division, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU )[1] 

# write results to disk
cv2.imwrite("green_card_thresh2.jpg", thresh2)

# display it
cv2.imshow("thresh1", thresh1)
cv2.imshow("thresh2", thresh2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Adaptive Thresholding Result:

[image]

Division Normalization Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, fmw42. I have tried your solutions, but it seems not good when the light condition varies.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

since there are different lighting conditions, contrast adjustment is added here.

The simple approache in my mind to solve your issue is that: since the undesired background colours are Green and Red, and the desired font colour is Black, simply suppress the Red and green colours as following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.io import imread, imsave
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
from skimage import exposure


def adjustContrast(img):
    p2, p98 = np.percentile(img, (2, 98))
    img_rescale = exposure.rescale_intensity(img, in_range=(p2, p98))
    return img_rescale

# Read the image
img = imread('ID_OCR.jpg')

# Contrast Adjustment for each channel

img[:,:,0] = adjustContrast(img[:,:,0]) # R
img[:,:,1] = adjustContrast(img[:,:,1]) # G
img[:,:,2] = adjustContrast(img[:,:,2]) # B

# # Supress unwanted colors

img[img[...,0] > 100] = 255 # R
img[img[...,1] > 100] = 255 # B


# Convert the image to graylevel
img = rgb2gray(img)

# Rescale into 0-255
img = 255*img.astype(np.uint8)

# Save the results
imsave('Result.png', img)
```

The image will look like:

[image]

The Results are not optimal, because also your **image resolution isn't high**.

At the end, there are many solutions, and improvements, also you can use Morphology to make it look nicer, this is just a simple proposal to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions. The result is not good enough when I test on different light conditions.

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: The outputs returned from your code here:[https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jyscCEfY_0-7wOwJLyC6FiyB09Rq1vOM?usp=sharing]